# How to get the value from if else

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

*Hello, everyone!

How do I get the result from the block?*

```
  if (result.valid) {
    const test = result.length_valid 
  } else {
    console.log('...');
  }
console.log(test)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question need to include a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to focus on your issue. In your case, please post the errors in your console.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first check whether result.valid is true or false. Then, you should define "test" variable using let or var outside the "if" block. Variables declared/defined using const and let keywords are block-scoped and you can't get their values outside the block.

```
    let test;
    if (result.valid) {
        test = result.length_valid 
    } else {
        console.log('...');
    }
    console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test;
if (result.valid) {
    test = result.length_valid;
} else {
    console.log('...');
}
console.log(test)
```

Comment: don't work :( hhm

Comment: @julia Probably because the `result.valid` condition is falsy. Can you `console.log(result.valid)`?